# podman run with --init gives me: Error: container-init binary not found on the host: stat /usr/libexec/podman/catatonit: no such file or directory

Tags: init, podman, buildah

When I run `podman run --init`, I get

```
$> podman run --init -ti cp /sbin/init
Error: container-init binary not found on the host: stat /usr/libexec/podman/catatonit: no such file or directory
```

But I can easily verify that there is an init there,

```
$> podman run cp ls -- /sbin | grep init
init
telinit
```

What is `catatonit`? Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn’t complaining about `/sbin/init` but about `/usr/libexec/podman/catatonit`, which points to `/usr/libexec/catatonit/catatonit`. The latter is provided by the `catatonit` package which is presumably not installed on your system (it’s only a weak dependency for `podman`).

On Fedora,

```
sudo dnf install catatonit
```

should fix things (but the package should be installed for you if you install `podman`).

On Debian, you’re running into [#971815](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=971815); you’ll have to either wait for a fix for that bug, or provide your own container `init`. One method is

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/docker-init /usr/libexec/podman/catatonit
```

or configure `podman` to use `docker-init` directly instead of `catatonit` (in `~/.config/containers/containers.conf`).

```
[containers]
init_path="/usr/bin/docker-init"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install container-init binary and define it p in **containers.conf**, such as tini:

```
[containers]
init_path= "/usr/bin/tini"
```

Maybe don't need it at all:

```
[containers]
init = false
```